# Token Names names must finish with "token"?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I am creating my own token on ERC20 standard, but I am not sure if every token has to finish on "token". For example: I want to create a token named Star, has the name to be Star Token, or it can just be Star?

Answer (score 0):

It can just be `Star`, there's no constraint on the name.

This is done purely for readability.